# Solving huge equations

Tags: equation-solving

I have this expression:

$d=-\frac{\sqrt{\frac{780 (f+130) \left(5 d^2 (13 c+f+130)-5 d (c (f+1300)-325 (f+160))+125 \left(2 (2 c+725) f+5 f^2+104000\right)+13 d^3\right)
   \left(5 d^2 (52 c+17 f+2600)+5 d \left(c (61 f+5200)+5 \left(f^2+290 f+20800\right)\right)-25 c f (f+80)+52 d^3\right) \left(300 c^2 (13 d-f)+5 c
   \left(208 d^2+d (121 f-2600)-5 \left(f^2+1280 f+156000\right)\right)+d \left(52 d^2+5 d (17 f+2600)+25 \left(f^2+290
   f+20800\right)\right)\right)}{\left(5 d (13 c+f-130)-5 ((c+100) f+13000)+13 d^2\right)^3}+\left(-\frac{13 \left(5 d^2 (52 c+17 f+2600)+5 d \left(c
   (61 f+5200)+5 \left(f^2+290 f+20800\right)\right)-25 c f (f+80)+52 d^3\right)^2}{4 \left(5 d (13 c+f-130)-5 ((c+100) f+13000)+13
   d^2\right)^2}+\frac{(25 (5 f+728)-780 c) \left(5 d^2 (52 c+17 f+2600)+5 d \left(c (61 f+5200)+5 \left(f^2+290 f+20800\right)\right)-25 c f
   (f+80)+52 d^3\right)}{4 \left(5 d (13 c+f-130)-5 ((c+100) f+13000)+13 d^2\right)}+975 c (f+80)\right)^2}+\frac{13 \left(5 d^2 (52 c+17 f+2600)+5 d
   \left(c (61 f+5200)+5 \left(f^2+290 f+20800\right)\right)-25 c f (f+80)+52 d^3\right)^2}{4 \left(5 d (13 c+f-130)-5 ((c+100) f+13000)+13
   d^2\right)^2}+\frac{195 c \left(5 d^2 (52 c+17 f+2600)+5 d \left(c (61 f+5200)+5 \left(f^2+290 f+20800\right)\right)-25 c f (f+80)+52 d^3\right)}{5
   d (13 c+f-130)-5 ((c+100) f+13000)+13 d^2}-\frac{125 f \left(5 d^2 (52 c+17 f+2600)+5 d \left(c (61 f+5200)+5 \left(f^2+290
   f+20800\right)\right)-25 c f (f+80)+52 d^3\right)}{4 \left(5 d (13 c+f-130)-5 ((c+100) f+13000)+13 d^2\right)}-\frac{4550 \left(5 d^2 (52 c+17
   f+2600)+5 d \left(c (61 f+5200)+5 \left(f^2+290 f+20800\right)\right)-25 c f (f+80)+52 d^3\right)}{5 d (13 c+f-130)-5 ((c+100) f+13000)+13 d^2}-975
   c f-78000 c}{104 \left(-\frac{5 d^2 (52 c+17 f+2600)+5 d \left(c (61 f+5200)+5 \left(f^2+290 f+20800\right)\right)-25 c f (f+80)+52 d^3}{4 \left(5
   d (13 c+f-130)-5 ((c+100) f+13000)+13 d^2\right)}-15 c\right)}$

The raw mathematica input for this is:

```
func = -(((13*(52*d^3 + 5*(52*c + 17*f + 2600)*d^2 + 5*(c*(61*f + 5200) + 5*(f^2 + 290*f + 20800))*d - 25*c*f*(f + 80))^2)/
  (4*(13*d^2 + 5*(13*c + f - 130)*d - 5*((c + 100)*f + 13000))^2) + 
 (195*c*(52*d^3 + 5*(52*c + 17*f + 2600)*d^2 + 5*(c*(61*f + 5200) + 5*(f^2 + 290*f + 20800))*d - 25*c*f*(f + 80)))/
  (13*d^2 + 5*(13*c + f - 130)*d - 5*((c + 100)*f + 13000)) - 
 (4550*(52*d^3 + 5*(52*c + 17*f + 2600)*d^2 + 5*(c*(61*f + 5200) + 5*(f^2 + 290*f + 20800))*d - 25*c*f*(f + 80)))/
  (13*d^2 + 5*(13*c + f - 130)*d - 5*((c + 100)*f + 13000)) - 
 (125*f*(52*d^3 + 5*(52*c + 17*f + 2600)*d^2 + 5*(c*(61*f + 5200) + 5*(f^2 + 290*f + 20800))*d - 25*c*f*(f + 80)))/
  (4*(13*d^2 + 5*(13*c + f - 130)*d - 5*((c + 100)*f + 13000))) - 78000*c - 975*c*f + 
 Sqrt[(-((13*(52*d^3 + 5*(52*c + 17*f + 2600)*d^2 + 5*(c*(61*f + 5200) + 5*(f^2 + 290*f + 20800))*d - 25*c*f*(f + 80))^2)/
       (4*(13*d^2 + 5*(13*c + f - 130)*d - 5*((c + 100)*f + 13000))^2)) + ((25*(5*f + 728) - 780*c)*(52*d^3 + 5*(52*c + 17*f + 2600)*d^2 + 
        5*(c*(61*f + 5200) + 5*(f^2 + 290*f + 20800))*d - 25*c*f*(f + 80)))/(4*(13*d^2 + 5*(13*c + f - 130)*d - 5*((c + 100)*f + 13000))) + 
     975*c*(f + 80))^2 + (780*(f + 130)*(13*d^3 + 5*(13*c + f + 130)*d^2 - 5*(c*(f + 1300) - 325*(f + 160))*d + 
      125*(5*f^2 + 2*(2*c + 725)*f + 104000))*(52*d^3 + 5*(52*c + 17*f + 2600)*d^2 + 5*(c*(61*f + 5200) + 5*(f^2 + 290*f + 20800))*d - 
      25*c*f*(f + 80))*(300*(13*d - f)*c^2 + 5*(208*d^2 + (121*f - 2600)*d - 5*(f^2 + 1280*f + 156000))*c + 
      d*(52*d^2 + 5*(17*f + 2600)*d + 25*(f^2 + 290*f + 20800))))/(13*d^2 + 5*(13*c + f - 130)*d - 5*((c + 100)*f + 13000))^3])/
(104*(-15*c - (52*d^3 + 5*(52*c + 17*f + 2600)*d^2 + 5*(c*(61*f + 5200) + 5*(f^2 + 290*f + 20800))*d - 25*c*f*(f + 80))/
   (4*(13*d^2 + 5*(13*c + f - 130)*d - 5*((c + 100)*f + 13000))))))
```

I want to solve for $func=d$ for real solutions. I'm using

```
Solve[func==d, d, Reals]
```

It seems to run for ages - will it complete? Is this the way I should be doing it?

Comment: If this takes too long, maybe you should consider whether you really need the analytic solution. Depending on what you do, it may be sufficient to find solutions for given numeric values of $f$ and $c$ (in which case you can wait with `Solve` until you have inserted those values, thus giving a much simpler expression to solve). You might even not need the complete set of solutions, in which case you may consider using `FindInstance` after inserting values.

Comment: I would prefer the analytic solution as it will eventually be put in a different executable. I am coming to the realisation that I will have to solve it numerically by calling out to mathematica's NSolve from C++

Comment: Well, I managed to get a result by rewriting the equation to get rid of the square root. The results are in terms of `Root` objects and `ConditionalExpression`s and take many tens of pages. That won't do you any good.

Comment: Thanks for the effort @SjoerdC.deVries. The Numerical Solution is fast so I will just call out to mathematica from C

Answer (score 2):

You can get an approximate analytical solution within a domain of other parameters using numerical solution. First get an idea of the nature of your function.

```
Plot[{func /. {c -> 1.5, f -> 1.5}, d}, {d, -1000, 1000}]
```

[image]

I can see there are two solutions - near 0 and near -500.

```
FindRoot[Block[{c = 1.5, f = 1.5}, func] == d, {d, 0}]
FindRoot[Block[{c = 1.5, f = 1.5}, func] == d, {d, -500}]
```

> {d -> 0.00831943}
>
> {d -> -375.409}

Let's focus on the solutions near 0.

```
data = Flatten[Table[{c, f, d /. FindRoot[func - d, {d, 0.01}]}
                   , {c, 0.1,  2, .1}, {f, 0.1, 2, .1}], 1];
ListPlot3D[data]
func1[x_, y_] = Interpolation[data][x, y]
```

[image]

and `func1[x,y]` is your approximate solution within the domain.